# jquery no response on event second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to show/hide a `<div>` using jQuery. But the problem is that the show and and hide works only once. Here's my HTML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#show_div').html('this is div to appear<button id="button2" >two</button>');

      $('#button2').click(function(){
      $('#show_div').hide();
   });  
 });
});
</script>

<body>
  <button id="button1">one</button>
  <div id="show_div"></div>
</body>
```

Now when I click button 'one' 'show_div' appears fine + button 'two'. Then when I click button 'two' both 'show_div' and button 'two' disappear. But when I click button 'one' again nothing happens.

I know the explanation may be very simple but I do not understand.

Answer (score 2):

It is not shown because you should show the div too.
Try using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function(){
     $('#show_div').show();
    $('#show_div').html('this is div to appear<button id="button2" >two</button>');

      $('#button2').click(function(){
      $('#show_div').hide();
   });  
 });
});
</script>

<body>
<button id="button1">one</button>
<div id="show_div"></div>


</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to show the div whenever button 1 is pressed:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button1').click(function(){
    $('#show_div').show();   // <-- here
    $('#show_div').html('this is div to appear<button id="button2" >two</button>');

      $('#button2').click(function(){
      $('#show_div').hide();
   });  
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

insted call hide method, clear the HTML content.

```
$('#show_div').html("");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are hiding the div #show_div when button2 is clicked , the #show_div get the style display:none.

when you click #button1 again it replaces the html but the div is still hidden.

maybe try this , $('#show_div').show() , display the div again

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){

         $('#show_div').show();
         $('#show_div').html('this is div to appear<button id="button2" >two</button>');
         $('#button2').click(function(){
             $('#show_div').hide();
         });  
   });
  });
</script>
```